# Stored procedure using insert and select statements

Tags: mysql, select, stored-procedures, insert

I want to get the adminID from ADMIN table using the email and save the adminID in the product table. I tried do that, it returns null in the adminID in Product table. Please let me know where I'm making a mistake.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE prc_saveProduct
(
    IN inputuserEmail VARCHAR(255),
    inputproductName VARCHAR(255),
    inputpoints INT(11),
)
BEGIN 
    SET @AdminID = (SELECT AdminID FROM ADMIN WHERE email = inputuserEmail );

    INSERT INTO PRODUCTS(AdminID, productName, points)
    VALUES (@AdminID, inputproductName, inputpoints);
END
```

Comment: can you post your table architecture and data

Comment: In your insert statement, you can't have a comma "," after points, and inputpoints,    That is your issue.  i posted the full answer below with the corrected insert into statement syntax.  You also have an extra comma in the declaring of the params for the proc after INT(11) that can't be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `yourSchema`.`prc_saveProduct`(
    p_inputuserEmail VARCHAR(255), 
    p_inputproductname VARCHAR(255),
    p_inputpoints INT(11)
)
    BEGIN

    DECLARE _AdminID VARCHAR(255);

    SELECT
        AdminID FROM ADMIN WHERE email = p_inputuserEmail
    INTO
        _AdminID;

    INSERT INTO PRODUCTS(
    AdminID, 
    productName, 
    points
    )
    VALUES
    (
    _AdminID,
    p_inputproductName,
    p_inputpoints
    );  


    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

the p_ is not necessary, I just like to prepend proc params with it to distinguish it.  The underscore I like to use for local variables "_AdminID", but that's not necessary either. I just prefer those naming conventions.

Comment: you have changes a session variable to local..what does it impact.does it will work??

Comment: It will work.  It would only have impact if after he calls this stored proc he needs that session variable in some other process to have the AdminID value to use it later in the same session.

Comment: sorry thats my mistake... there are few more values that's why... while editing i forgot to take out those comma's @Jordan